# Windows Phone Emulator error - Couldn't change Processor of the virtual machine

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, windows-mobile, virtual-machine

I have VisualStudio 2012 update 4 with Windows 8.1 Premier OS (64 bit). I just created simple windows mobile application from new project option in VS2012 and tried to run. I got the below error message

`The Windows Phone Emulator wasn't able to create the virtual machine:
Couldn't change Processor of the virtual machine:
'Emulator WVGA 512MB.admin' failed to modify device
'Processor'. (Virtual machien ID #######-#####-####-######)
Cannot assign the specified number of processors for
virtual machine 'Emulator WVGA 512MB.admin' is our of
range. The range is 1 through 1. (Virtual machine ID #####-#####-######`

I am new to windows mobile development. Please explain how can I avoid this error.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is resolved by altering the process count by 2 in the Hyper-V manager.

[image]

Comment: Does not work, Emulator does not show up in Hyper-V Manager